# REST API filter operator best practice

Tags: api, rest

I am building a REST API that uses a `filter` parameter to control search results. E.g., one could search for a user by calling:

```
GET /users/?filter=name%3Dfoo
```

Now, my API should allow many different `filter` operators. **Numeric operators** such as `equals`, `greater than`, `less than`, **string operators** like `contains`, `begins with` or `ends with` and **date operators** such as `year of` or `timediff`. Moreover, `AND` and `OR` combinations should be possible.
Basically, I want to support a subset of the underlying MySQL database operators.

I found a lot of different implementations (two good examples are [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=de#filters) and [LongJump](http://lj.platformatyourservice.com/wiki/REST_API:Filter_Expressions_in_REST_APIs)) that seem to use custom syntax.
Looking at my requirements, I would probably design a custom syntax pretty similiar to the MySQL operator syntax.
**However, I was wondering if there are any best practices established that I should follow and whether I should consider anything else.** Thanks!

Comment: have you tried/heard of SPARQL?

Comment: No, let me take a look

Comment: Look at [Solr queries](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) (they are done via HTTP GET too). I can also imagine a [MongoDB-like query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) (with json and url encoding).

Answer (score 21):

You need an already existing query language, don't try to reinvent the wheel! By REST this is complicated and not fully solved issue. There are some REST constraints your application must fulfill:

- uniform interface / hypermedia as the engine of application state:
  You have to send hypermedia responses to your clients, and they have to follow the hyperlinks given in those responses, instead of building the requests on their own. So you can decouple the clients from the structure of the URI.
- uniform interface / self-descriptive messages:
  You have to send messages annotated with semantics. So you can decouple the clients from the data structure. The best solution to do this is RDF with for example open linked data vocabs. If you don't want to use RDF, then the second best solution to use a vendor specific MIME type, so your messages will be self-descriptive, but the clients need to know how to parse your custom MIME type.

To describe simple search links, you can use [URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), for example `GET /users/{?name}` will wait a `name` parameter in the query string. You can use the `hydra:IRITemplateMapping` from the [hydra vocab](http://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/core/) to add semantics to the paramers like `name`.

Describing ad-hoc queries is a hard task. You have to describe somehow what your query can contain.

- You can choose an URI query language and stick with URI templates and probably hydra annotation. There are many already existing [URI query languages](http://dataprotocols.org/data-query-protocol/), like [HTSQL](http://htsql.org/), [OData query](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/) (ppl don't like that one), etc...
- You can choose an existing query language and send it in a single URI param. This can be anything you want, for example SQL, SPARQL, etc... You have to teach your client to generate that param. You can create your own vocab to describe the constraints of the actual query. If you don't need complicated things, this should not be a problem. I don't know of already existing query structure descibing vocabs, but I never looked for them...
- You can choose an existing query language and send it in the body in a [SEARCH request](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5323/?include_text=1). Afaik SEARCH is not cached or supported by recent HTTP clients. It was defined by webdav. You can describe your query with the proper MIME type, and you can use the same vocab as by the previous solution.
- You can use an RDF query solution, for example a [SPARQL endpoint](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/), or [triple pattern fragments](http://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/triple-pattern-fragments/), etc... So your queries will contain the semantic metadata, and not your link description. By SPARQL you don't necessary need a triple data storage, you can translate the queries on server side to SQL, or whatever you use. You can probably use [SPIN](http://www.w3.org/Submission/spin-modeling/) to describe query constraints and query templates, but that is new for me too. There might be other solutions to describe SPARQL query structures...

So to summarize if you want a real REST solution, you have to describe to your clients, how they can construct the queries and what parameters, logical operators they can use.  Without query descriptions they won't be able to generate for example a HTML form for the user. If you don't want a REST solution, then pick a query language write a builder on the client, write a parser on the server and that's all.

Answer (score 14):

[The Open Data Protocol (OData)](http://www.odata.org/)

You can check [BreezeJs](http://www.breezejs.com) too and see how this protocol it's implemented for node.js + mongodb with breeze-mongodb module and for a .NET project using Web API and EntityFramework  with Breeze.ContextProvider dll.

Answer (score 3):

By embracing a set of common, accepted delimiters, equality comparison can be implemented in
straight-forward fashion. Setting the value of the filter query-string parameter to a string using those
delimiters creates a list of name/value pairs which can be parsed easily on the server-side and utilized
to enhance database queries as needed. You can use the delimeters of your choice say (“|”) to separate individual filter phrases for OR and ("&") to separate 
individual filter phrases for AND and a double colon (“::”) to separate the names and values.
This provides a unique-enough set of delimiters to support the majority of use cases and creates a user readable
query-string parameter. A simple example will serve to clarify the technique. Suppose we want
to request users with the name “Todd” who live in "Denver" and have the title of “Grand Poobah”.

The request URI, complete with query-string might look like this:

GET http://www.example.com/users?filter="name::todd&city::denver&title::grand poobah”

The delimiter of the double colon (“::”) separates the property name from the comparison value,
enabling the comparison value to contain spaces—making it easier to parse the delimiter from the value
on the server.
Note that the property names in the name/value pairs match the name of the properties that would be
returned by the service in the payload.

Case sensitivity is certainly up for debate on a case-by-case basis, but in general,
filtering works best when case is ignored. You can also offer wild-cards as needed using the asterisk
(“*”) as the value portion of the name/value pair.
For queries that require more-than simple equality or wild-card comparisons, introduction of operators
is necessary. In this case, the operators themselves should be part of the value and parsed on the server
side, rather than part of the property name. When complex query-language-style functionality is
needed, consider introducing query concept from the Open Data Protocol (OData) Filter System Query
Option specification (http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-4-0/)

Comment: Your answer does not look like **established best practice** (OP's question) it looks more like adhoc opinion. Can you add reference to a source where is this kind of filter used?

Comment: This answer seems to be copy pasted from http://www.restapitutorial.com/resources.html (see the PDF document, page 27/28 as of 2016-11-04)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lot of standards (like OData), but many are quite complicated in that they introduce new syntax.

For simple multi filtering the following format avoid polluting the parameter namespace while still standing on top of existing web-technology

```
GET /users?filter[name]=John&filter[title]=Manager
```

It's easily readable and on the backend languages like PHP will receive it as an array of filters to apply.

Comment: what about "or" filters?

Comment: That falls into the non-simple ;-) You can do it in two requests. I suppose you could do it like `GET /users?filterOr[0][name]=John&filterOr[0][name]=Eva`

Comment: A basic OR filter is not "non-simple" and a second request is not a solution; it's a workaround to a badly designed query system.

Comment: you can build your query like `(CreateDate[lt]2018-12-20 or Creator[eq]"Jalal") and IsNew[eq]true` the e.g is take from this [repository](https://github.com/Jalalx/LhsBracketParser#readme) which implements the 'strategy' in C# but you got the idea, and remember after parsing the syntax think of validating the yielded parameters.

Comment: What if the name is `John&filter[title]=Manager`? One needs to be able to easily escape values.

Answer (score 0):

A possible standard would [SCIM](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-scim-api-12) which is adopted by some commercial products. But it's not distinguished by brevity. For a pet project I used this

- = equal
- ! not equal
- * like
- < smaller
- `>` greater
- & bitwise and
- | bitwise or
- ^ bitwise xor
- ~ in comma separated value list

Examples

So `GET /user?name=*An*` would get all users whose name start with An and `GET /user?name=~Anna,Bertha` would get those two users.

Not yet a standard but who knows...